# Save dual monitor setup on KDE debian 8

Tags: debian, kde, desktop-environment, multi-monitor

I've just updated from Debian 7 to Debian 8 (please don't ask why just now). I'm now trying to save my monitor configuration, so it is the same after a reboot. My monitors are there and if I go into the KDE control panel, I just have to check the checkbox to activate the second monitor and drag it to the correct position. I have to do it every time I restart my system -- why? It worked with Debian 7. What I can I do to make it stay?

I have the following "graphics card": VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)